# If $3\sin^2{B}+7\sin^2{C}=2\sin^2{A}+2\sin{A}\sin{B}\sin{C}$, then is $\sin{A}=\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$？

Tags: trigonometry

> In $\Delta ABC$,such
>   $$3\sin^2{B}+7\sin^2{C}=2\sin^2{A}+2\sin{A}\sin{B}\sin{C}$$
>   and such $a=|BC|=1$, show that $$\sin{A}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$$

I think this problem

$$3b^2+7c^2=2a^2+2\sin{A}bc=2+\sin{A}\cdot bc$$
where $|AC|=b,|AB|=c$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $3b^2+7c^2=2a^2+2\sin{A}bc=2+\sin{A}\cdot bc$

This should be 
$$3b^2+7c^2=2a^2+2\sin{A}bc=2+\color{red}{2}\sin{A}\cdot bc$$
from which we have
$$\sin A=\frac{3b^2+7c^2-2}{2bc}\tag1$$
By the way, by the law of cosines,
$$\cos A=\frac{b^2+c^2-1}{2bc}\tag2$$
Using that $\sin^2A+\cos^2A=1$ with $(1)(2)$,
$$\left(\frac{3b^2+7c^2-2}{2bc}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b^2+c^2-1}{2bc}\right)^2=1$$
Multiplying the both sides by $(2bc)^2$ gives
$$(3b^2+7c^2-2)^2+(b^2+c^2-1)^2-(2bc)^2=0$$
which can be written as
$$10\left(b^2+\frac{20c^2-7}{10}\right)^2+\frac{1}{10}(10c^2-1)^2=0$$
from which we have
$$b^2+\frac{20c^2-7}{10}=10c^2-1=0,$$
i.e.
$$b=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2},\quad c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$$
The claim follows from $(1)$.